# How does $\frac{7}{\sqrt{{49-49x}}}$ simplify to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{{1-1x}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand the concept here. I fundamentally have not grasped how the expression is simplified from

$$\frac{7}{\sqrt{{49-49x}}}$$
to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{{1-1x}}}$$

I understand that the numerator is the sqrt of the constant and coefficient under the radical in the denominator.

I'm hoping someone can explain the steps to this process.

Comment: $\sqrt{{49-49x}} = \sqrt{7^2(1-x)} = 7 \sqrt{1-x}$ since $7\ge 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{7}{\sqrt{{49-49x}}} = \frac{7}{\sqrt{{49(1-x})}}= \frac{7}{\sqrt{49}\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac{7}{7\sqrt{{1-x}}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{{1-x}}}$$